# Spark: Multiple filter inside agg and concat not null values

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to concatenate not null values from a List column.
I know this can be done easily by using UDF but would like to know how to handle this by using multiple filter conditions inside **agg** function.
Don't know what's missing here?

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("foo", List(null,"bar",null)), 
                            ("bar", List("one","two",null)),
                            ("rio", List("Ria","","Kevin")))).toDF("key", "value")

+---+-----------------+
|key|            value|
+---+-----------------+
|foo|[null, bar, null]|
|bar| [one, two, null]|
|rio|   [Ria, , Kevin]|
+---+-----------------+                         

df.groupBy("key")
  .agg(concat_ws(",",first(when(($"value".isNotNull || $"value" =!= ""),$"value"))).as("RemovedNullSeq"))
  .show(false)

+---+--------------+
|key|RemovedNullSeq|
+---+--------------+
|bar|one,two       |
|rio|Ria,,Kevin    |
|foo|bar           |
+---+--------------+
```

I don't need that blank value in the second record.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("foo", List(null,"bar",null)), 
                            ("bar", List("one","two",null)),
                            ("rio", List("Ria","","Kevin")))).toDF("key", "value")

val filtd = df.select($"key" as "key", explode($"value") as "val").where (length($"val") > 0)
val rsult = filtd.select($"*").groupBy($"key").agg(collect_list("val"))
rsult.show(5)
```

You can add ultiple conditions like this

```
val filtd = df.select($"key" as "key", explode($"value") as "val").where (length($"val") > 0 && $"val".isNotNull)
```

Output

```
+---+-----------------+
|key|collect_list(val)|
+---+-----------------+
|bar|       [one, two]|
|rio|     [Ria, Kevin]|
|foo|            [bar]|
+---+-----------------+
```

Comment: @@Abhi, Thanks for your reply! 
Thought somebody would correct my answer. Was also not sure whatever I was asking makes any sense or not :)
But anyways, I will accept your answer as it helped.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not immediately sure if using aggregate functions is necessary based on the example provided.

If you're just trying to concatenate the values in an array then the following works:

```
val df = Seq(List(null,"abc", null),
    List(null, null, null), 
    List(null, "def", "ghi", "kjl"),
    List("mno", null, "pqr")).toDF("list")

df.withColumn("concat", concat_ws(",",$"list")).show(false)

+---------------------+-----------+
|list                 |concat     |
+---------------------+-----------+
|[null, abc, null]    |abc        |
|[null, null, null]   |           |
|[null, def, ghi, kjl]|def,ghi,kjl|
|[mno, null, pqr]     |mno,pqr    |
+---------------------+-----------+
```

If there is a need to group first:

```
val df2 = Seq((123,List(null,"abc", null)),
    (123,List(null,"def", "hij"))).toDF("key","list")

df2.show(false)
+---+-----------------+
|key|list             |
+---+-----------------+
|123|[null, abc, null]|
|123|[null, def, hij] |
+---+-----------------+
```

You might think you could do something like

```
val grouped = df2.groupBy($"key").agg(collect_list($"list").as("collected"))
```

And then apply some functions to the array of arrays to obtain your concatenated result. However, I have been unable to find a way to do this without resorting to UDFs.

In this case, exploding before the grouping does the trick:

```
val grouped = df2.groupBy($"key").agg(collect_list($"list").as("collected"))
    .groupBy($"key").agg(collect_list($"listItem").as("collected"))
    .withColumn("concat", concat_ws(",",$"collected")).show(false)

+---+---------------+-----------+
|key|collected      |concat     |
+---+---------------+-----------+
|123|[abc, def, hij]|abc,def,hij|
+---+---------------+-----------+
```

Note however that there is no guarantee of the order in which the lists will be collected.

Hope this helps

Comment: @@user2682459, Thanks for your reply too!!